# Check if number is divisible by 24

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'd like to put up a if function, that will see if the variable is dividable by 24, if it's then it does the function else not, same logic however, I want to see if the output is a perfect number, e.g if we do 24/24 that will get 1, that's a perfect number. If we do 25/24 then it'll get 1.041 which is not a perfect number, the next perfect number will come when it reaches 48 that will be 48/24 which will get 2 that's a perfect number.

Comment: The key to solving this is the `%` operator. [This should](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) be enough to get you started

Comment: @ScottChamberlain can you please show me an example?

Comment: Isn't perfect number supposed to be 6, 28, 496... as outlined here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number

Comment: Side note: in future questions please avoid "thank you notes", "I'm new here", "I'm new to XXXX language" and similar text not related to problem itself

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Okay, I will keep in mind!

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use the [Modulus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) operator:

```
if (number % 24 == 0)
{
   ...
}
```

> The % operator computes the remainder after dividing its first operand
> by its second. All numeric types have predefined remainder operators.

Pretty much it returns the remainder of a division: 25 % 24 = 1 because 25 fits in 24 once, and you have 1 left. When the number fits perfectly you will get a 0 returned, and in your example that is how you know if a number is divisible by 24, otherwise the returned value will be greater than 0.

Answer (score 16):

How about using [Modulus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) operator

```
if (mynumber % 24 == 0)
{
     //mynumber is a Perfect Number
}
else
{
    //mynumber is not a Perfect Number
}
```

What it does

Unlike `/` which gives quotient, the  Modulus operator (`%`) gets the remainder of the division done on operands. Remainder is zero for perfect number and remainder is greater than zero for non perfect number.