# C# Using Bool, how to check a double is truly divisible by another number?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way of checking that a value is wholly divisible by another number, for example 1000 divided by 100 would be true, but 1115 divided by 100 would be false?

I am tring to

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: _"I am tring to ..."_  we are listening

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`%`-operator:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

```
bool isDivisible = 1115 % 100 == 0;
```

> The % operator computes the remainder after dividing its first operand
>   by its second. All numeric types have predefined remainder operators.

Comment: It's amazing that [no-one has asked this before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395334/check-if-number-is-divisible-by-24)

Comment: And it's amazing that a programmer like OP never heard of modulo before. Cause otherwise you'd just have to type "modulo c#" into google.

Comment: Thank you Tim, solved my problem immediately :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use mod operator (`%`) and check that remainder is equal to 0:

```
var result = (1000.00 % 100) == 0; // evaluates to true
var result = (1115.00 % 100) == 0; // evaluates to false
```

Comment: Those aren't `double`s :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out `%` operator. 1000 % 100 yields 0. 1115 % 100 yields 15